# LSTM Model accuracy is stuck in a certain level and doesn't change

Tags: python, hyperparameters

I'm working on a multivariate timeseries prediction using LSTM. I'm trying to get a better match between my actual and predicted values, but no matter what my hyperparamters are, the accuracy won't change. I was wondering if you can give me few insight on how to increase my model accuracy...

I have 3 inputs (time, two rates) and one output (pressure).

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oFMfJ.png)

This is the LSTM section of my code:

```
model = Sequential()
    model.add(LSTM(units=4,
                   activation='tanh',
                   recurrent_activation='hard_sigmoid',
                   use_bias=True,
                   unit_forget_bias=True,
                   dropout=0,
                   recurrent_dropout=0.3,
                   input_shape=(look_back, 3)))

    model.add(Dense(units=1,
                    activation='linear',
                    use_bias=True))

    model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='Adam', metrics=['mae','accuracy'])
    hist = model.fit(x_train, y_train,
                     epochs=50,
                     batch_size=20,
                     validation_split=0.0,
                     verbose=2,
                     shuffle=False)
```

Comment: Did you try increasing the number of units in the LSTM?

Comment: Yes, Ankit Goyal. But no difference...